# Wifi not working! RTL8723DE wifi, CentOS 7.7

Tags: centos, wifi, realtek, hp

I tried some methods which I got from askubuntu and still the issue persists.

```
#sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

I'm still getting this error! What should I do?

When i updated my kernel to 5.3 it is stuck while loading before the login screen..

I'm using CentOS 7.7

---

This is the log file. I didn't understand anything by reading this. I'm a beginner.

```
DKMS make.log for rtlwifi-new-0.6 for kernel 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 (x86_64)
Tue Oct  8 09:42:47 IST 2019
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:67:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_data’
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1990:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_data’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:77:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_zero’
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1981:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_zero’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:96:15: error: conflicting types for ‘time64_t’
 typedef __s32 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from include/linux/time.h:7:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:31,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:
include/linux/time64.h:6:15: note: previous declaration of ‘time64_t’ was here
 typedef __s64 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:54:27: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 #define NUM_NL80211_BANDS IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS
                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:1708:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUM_NL80211_BANDS’
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[NUM_NL80211_BANDS];
                                        ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:67:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_data’
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1990:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_data’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:77:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_zero’
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1981:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_zero’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:96:15: error: conflicting types for ‘time64_t’
 typedef __s32 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from include/linux/time.h:7:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:31,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:
include/linux/time64.h:6:15: note: previous declaration of ‘time64_t’ was here
 typedef __s64 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:33:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/pci.h:333:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_zalloc_consistent’
 pci_zalloc_consistent(struct pci_dev *hwdev, size_t size,
 ^
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:2148:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/pci.h:29,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:33:
include/linux/pci-dma-compat.h:29:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_zalloc_consistent’ was here
 pci_zalloc_consistent(struct pci_dev *hwdev, size_t size,
 ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:67:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_data’
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1990:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_data’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:77:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_zero’
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:54:27: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 #define NUM_NL80211_BANDS IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS
                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:1708:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUM_NL80211_BANDS’
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[NUM_NL80211_BANDS];
                                        ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1981:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_zero’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:532:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘long unsigned int[1]’ from type ‘int’
  hw->flags = IEEE80211_HW_SIGNAL_DBM |
            ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:96:15: error: conflicting types for ‘time64_t’
 typedef __s32 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from include/linux/time.h:7:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:31,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:
include/linux/time64.h:6:15: note: previous declaration of ‘time64_t’ was here
 typedef __s64 time64_t;
               ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:545:13: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘long unsigned int[1]’ and ‘int’)
   hw->flags |= IEEE80211_HW_SUPPORTS_PS |
             ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:550:13: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘long unsigned int[1]’ and ‘int’)
   hw->flags |= IEEE80211_HW_SUPPORTS_PS |
             ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:603:21: error: request for member ‘flags’ in something not a structure or union
    hw->wiphy->wowlan.flags = WIPHY_WOWLAN_MAGIC_PKT;
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:605:21: error: request for member ‘n_patterns’ in something not a structure or union
    hw->wiphy->wowlan.n_patterns =
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:607:21: error: request for member ‘pattern_min_len’ in something not a structure or union
    hw->wiphy->wowlan.pattern_min_len =
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:609:21: error: request for member ‘pattern_max_len’ in something not a structure or union
    hw->wiphy->wowlan.pattern_max_len =
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c: In function ‘rtlwifi_rate_mapping’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:1259:7: error: ‘IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ == hw->conf.chandef.chan->band) {
       ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.c:1259:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.c:25:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:54:27: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 #define NUM_NL80211_BANDS IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS
                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:1708:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUM_NL80211_BANDS’
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[NUM_NL80211_BANDS];
                                        ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:67:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_data’
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1990:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_data’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:77:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_zero’
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:33,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1981:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_zero’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:96:15: error: conflicting types for ‘time64_t’
 typedef __s32 time64_t;
               ^
In file included from include/linux/time.h:7:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:31,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:
include/linux/time64.h:6:15: note: previous declaration of ‘time64_t’ was here
 typedef __s64 time64_t;
               ^
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:54:27: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 #define NUM_NL80211_BANDS IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS
                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:1708:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUM_NL80211_BANDS’
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[NUM_NL80211_BANDS];
                                        ^
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.o] Error 1
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbt_precomp.h:36:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/rtl_btc.h:28,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:33:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/../pci.h:333:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_zalloc_consistent’
 pci_zalloc_consistent(struct pci_dev *hwdev, size_t size,
 ^
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:2148:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/../pci.h:29,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbt_precomp.h:36,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/rtl_btc.h:28,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:33:
include/linux/pci-dma-compat.h:29:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_zalloc_consistent’ was here
 pci_zalloc_consistent(struct pci_dev *hwdev, size_t size,
 ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c: In function ‘_rtl_add_wowlan_patterns’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:464:54: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern *patterns = wow->patterns;
                                                      ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:479:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
   if (patterns[i].pattern_len < 0 ||
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:479:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   if (patterns[i].pattern_len < 0 ||
               ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:480:7: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
       patterns[i].pattern_len > MAX_WOL_PATTERN_SIZE) {
       ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:480:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       patterns[i].pattern_len > MAX_WOL_PATTERN_SIZE) {
               ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:485:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
   pattern_os = patterns[i].pattern;
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:485:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   pattern_os = patterns[i].pattern;
                        ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:486:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
   mask_len = DIV_ROUND_UP(patterns[i].pattern_len, 8);
   ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:16:0,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:15,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/wifi.h:31,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:26:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:486:35: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   mask_len = DIV_ROUND_UP(patterns[i].pattern_len, 8);
                                   ^
include/uapi/linux/kernel.h:12:40: note: in definition of macro ‘__KERNEL_DIV_ROUND_UP’
 #define __KERNEL_DIV_ROUND_UP(n, d) (((n) + (d) - 1) / (d))
                                        ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:486:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘DIV_ROUND_UP’
   mask_len = DIV_ROUND_UP(patterns[i].pattern_len, 8);
              ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:487:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
   mask_os = patterns[i].mask;
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:487:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   mask_os = patterns[i].mask;
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:490:11: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
           patterns[i].pattern_len);
           ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:490:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
           patterns[i].pattern_len);
                   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:550:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct cfg80211_wowlan_trig_pkt_pattern’
   for (j = 12; j < patterns[i].pattern_len; j++) {
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:550:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   for (j = 12; j < patterns[i].pattern_len; j++) {
                            ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:27:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c: In function ‘rtl_op_configure_filter’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.h:31:3: error: ‘FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  (FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS | \
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:862:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTL_SUPPORTED_FILTERS’
  *new_flags &= RTL_SUPPORTED_FILTERS;
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.h:31:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  (FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS | \
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:862:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTL_SUPPORTED_FILTERS’
  *new_flags &= RTL_SUPPORTED_FILTERS;
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2272:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ampdu_action = rtl_op_ampdu_action,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2272:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtl_ops.ampdu_action’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2273:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .sw_scan_start = rtl_op_sw_scan_start,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2273:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtl_ops.sw_scan_start’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2274:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .sw_scan_complete = rtl_op_sw_scan_complete,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2274:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtl_ops.sw_scan_complete’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2278:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .flush = rtl_op_flush,
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.c:2278:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtl_ops.flush’) [enabled by default]
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: It tells you right in the error what to do. "Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information." Check that file and add any error messages to your question.

Comment: Welcome, you can [edit your question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/545696/edit) to add any useful information.

Comment: centos 7.7 is pretty old (kernel  3.10.0) and you're probably trying to build some current sources against your kernel; _if_ that's really the case, it may not work at all, no matter how hard you try.

Answer (score 0):

If that `rtlwifi-new` driver is [this one](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), it is supported on kernel versions 4.2 and later only.

You seem to be trying to use it with CentOS's default kernel, which is version 3.10.x (with a number of backported patches), so this driver package is too new for that kernel. For Ubuntu, it might be fine, but not for CentOS 7.x.

If you tried running a bleeding-edge 5.3 kernel on a basic CentOS 7.7 system, there are quite a few pitfalls in that. Did you get a pre-packaged version of that kernel from somewhere (where?) or did you compile it from source code yourself?

The ELRepo package repository apparently has a pre-packaged 5.3 kernel available for CentOS 7.x, with instructions: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-linux-kernel-5-on-centos-7/

If you compiled your own 5.3 kernel, its getting stuck at boot most likely means some driver that is essential to the functioning of your hardware was not selected in the kernel configuration.

Comment: The link you gave does not have 8723DE, i got it from somwhere else. But after I update from 4.2 to 5.3 kernel in CENTOS 8, wifi is not working...

I would roll back to 4.2.. How can i do that and will there be any issues if i did that? Some packags missing kinda issues??? @telcoM

Comment: If you did not yet uninstall the old kernel, it will still be selectable in the GRUB boot menu. Just select the 4.2 kernel to boot with it, and then remove the failed 5.3 kernel. But 4.2 is a strange kernel for CentOS 8: by default, it should have 4.18, which is newer than 4.2.

Comment: oh ys... Its 4.18.. And I'm using this one only

Could you please let me know how to uninstall the unwanted kernel versions?

Comment: It depends on how you installed them: if they came from RPM packages, your package manager should be able to remove them. (Unlike normal packages, where package name and package version are two entirely separate things, on kernel packages the kernel version is usually part of the package name, so you can tell the package manager to e.g. "uninstall kernel-4.2" and it will leave the "kernel-4.18" alone. If you installed the 5.3 kernel from the source code, just reverse the steps you did to install it? I don't know what exactly you did, so I cannot recommend exact steps.